Unable to integrate microsoft azure sso login in flutter app using flutter_appauth
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.linusu.flutter_appauth.CallbackActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~oiOQSC4LyrKH8vDyPfAFKg==/com.marworx.ssoapp-ZpELo6-QfZ-R75H69XVGJg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~oiOQSC4LyrKH8vDyPfAFKg==/com.marworx.ssoapp-ZpELo6-QfZ-R75H69XVGJg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~oiOQSC4LyrKH8vDyPfAFKg==/com.marworx.ssoapp-ZpELo6-QfZ-R75H69XVGJg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
How to resolve this crashing issue in flutter android app

Can you share the code that you have tried?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The error ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.linusu.flutter_appauth.CallbackActivity" indicates that the required CallbackActivity class is missing from your project configuration. To resolve this issue, follow these steps:
Open the android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file and add the redirect URI scheme as shown below:
<activity
    android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="com.yourapp.app"
            android:host="oauthredirect" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>


Include the required dependencies in your pubspec.yaml file:
dependencies:
  flutter_appauth: ^5.0.0
flutter_microsoft_authentication: ^0.1.0
  http: ^0.15.0

Run flutter pub get to fetch the dependencies.
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.yourapp.app</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>


Thanks to @Gerrit van Huyssteen for the  steps. I referred  this  doc for Flutter Mobile SSO with Microsoft Login
import 'package:flutter_microsoft_authentication/flutter_microsoft_authentication.dart';
...
FlutterMicrosoftAuthentication fma = FlutterMicrosoftAuthentication(
  kClientID: "<client-id>",
  kAuthority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations",
  kScopes: ["User.Read", "User.ReadBasic.All"],
  androidConfigAssetPath: "assets/auth_config.json" 
);
String authToken = await this.fma.acquireTokenInteractively;
String authToken = await this.fma.acquireTokenSilently;
await this.fma.signOut;
await this.fma.loadAccount;




Thank you so much! it's working
